# Do dynamically-added CSS files get cached by the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, browser-cache

When I dynamically create a link element, and add it to the head to add a CSS file to a web page, does that file get cached?

Secondly, if it doesn't get cached, is there any way for me to have it get cached?

I'm asking browser side, if I can instruct the browser to cached the file?

Comment: if the url doesn't change it will cache as instructed by the server.

Comment: It depends on the cache-control header added on the server side -- the browser is instructed by the server.

Comment: Ok so it looks like I can add the cache-control header via htaccess/isapi like posit labs suggests below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does get cached. You can control caching by modifying your site's `.htaccess` file.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html